Movie scene where the main villain has to start a motor on his pelvis
In this movie scene villain is attempting to rape the heroine. Most of the villain's body part are made up some kind of machine. To do this act he has to start the motor on his pelvic (hip). He pulls the wire motor starts and then dialogue exchange between him and heroine.
Things that I remember from scene, that might help and might not, because I watched this movie long back, don't remember exact. So:

Villain is white guy and bald
Villain's head is not a machine
Heroine is blonde (not sure)
Heroine is at villain's place (captured)
Villain's place is also a machine, somekind of huge plane , drone
Villain's machine are working on some kind liquid, green in color
Movie is old, between 1990-2000
Villain is known actor, veteran actor


Pretty sure you're looking for sci-fi comedy Space Truckers from 1996 with Dennis Hopper and Stephen Dorff. The villain in question is Captain Macanudo (Charles Dance) who rebuilt his body with machine parts. In this particular scene he shows the captured heroine his robotic, er attachment that he starts with a pull cord and is powered by a tube full of green liquid. The heroine is Debi Mazar, though, who's not blonde. Here's the trailer:



